QGIS 3.38.3 - 75min startup
QGIS on Windows 11 (Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631) was freezing on startup. It would run through the logo window and display "QGIS ready" - then freeze.
I deleted the user profile folders, which didn't seem to make a difference.
Today I walked away while it was frozen - came back a few hours later and it was running fine. Debug Tools > Startup time > 'Show main window' took 4601.46s
No other items items took more than 0.1s.
Where would I start to debug this?

Perhaps start looking at hiding some/all drive letters - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/371451/2856 - and seeing if there's a problematic one.

How did you exactly installed QGIS? Are you sure you deleted the correct folder of the user profile actually used by QGIS? Have you tried to create a new QGIS user profile ad use it? Have you tried to disable any antivirus / antimalware on your system? Is your Internet connection working? Have you tried to disable the QGIS version check on startup and the display of the news feed on welcome page https://tinyurl.com/278mhtjr and the plugins version check on startup https://tinyurl.com/yc69w2dz?
Are there on your system drive letters connected to unavailable network shares?

Is this the first time you installed QGIS un your system? if not, did the issue also occur using a previous QGIS version?

@AndreaGiudiceandrea - I installed using the OSGeo4W Network Installer. I've been upgrading (and occasionally reinstalling) since about verison 3.0. Probably continupsly on this machine since about 3.18. Profiles - I renamed the entire Profiles directory, and it recreated on the next start. Malware - no (and I will), but there was no change to previous conditions. Internet is good.  Plugins - I usually keep most of them disabled after I saw their impact on general startup times. Unavailable network shares - Il'll check this (in a few hours) - is there a variable to reduce the timeout?

QGIS has occasionally had issues in the past - but I've always put that down to me tinkering with python paths, etc. A clean reinstall has fixed it when I've really broken it.  But this time - I don't think it was me!

Have you considered the proposed solutions here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/403346/78414 ?

Amongst a few other plugin issues - it turns out that the culprit was the unavailable network shares.
